# Making menu option in Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm playing about with the Sonata Admin Bundle but really struggling with how to get anything done. I can normally get by with reading the docs, but not having much luck with this one. I can't find how to make a dropdown menu or menu option in the top bar (Content, E-commerce, Classification in the demo*)... or even tabs like on content>media in the demo*

*http://demo.sonata-project.org/admin/login (P:admin,U:admin)

Comment: Add your admin service in config file, after automatic generate menu on the top bar.
pls, read http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/dashboard.html#using-the-config-yml

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

[knpmenubundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)

Sonata Admin bundle use it to create his menu, you can use it  to personalize your menu.